# Spring Boot CSRF

Tags: spring-boot, csrf-protection

Tried to implement CSRF protection on the latest Spring Boot.
All the examples on internet are based on user login and authentication, which I do not need.

My site does not have any sections requiring authentication.
I would like

> 1) Rest requests come from within site. No direct request from outside with wget to be allowed.
>
> 2) All pages (routes) must be requested from the index page (/)

**Included the security dependency in `pom.xml`**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

-- Defined users in `application.properties` (even though, I do not need)

-- App creates `_csrf.token` .

-- Created class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with "configure" method overriding.

Tried all suggested filters in "configure". It did not work and finally left it blank.

The problem is that Wget can get api pages directly.
How to prevent it?

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot do what you are saying here without some authentication so you would have to have implied authorization. I assume you have read through this http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html to make sure things are right.  In an app we have we have to specifically disable CSRF for non-browser items so it should work.  Please post your best configuration and classes that you think should be working.  A GitHub example may be easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've quickly put together a POC of this configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@SpringBootApplication
public class StackoverflowQ40929943Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowQ40929943Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

The gist of it is Spring Boot + Security will secure all endpoints automatically.  Here we explicitly allow requests to all endpoints.  But, Spring Boot + Security automatically configures CSRF out of the box which we've left enabled.  Thus you get the best of both worlds.

NOTE:  You'll probably need to refine this configuration further to meet your needs.

[Full Example on GitHub](https://github.com/kanderson450/stackoverflow-q40929943)

Comment: Tks. Tested yr code. It works when POST request is made directly to /endpoint.
Rightfully, When _csrf field is not included in POST request, I get error: (status=403).
Invalid CSRF Token '4afa89cc' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.<
But /endpoint controller responses to GET requests without control.
Even if I add a wrong  'X-CSRF-TOKEN' or '_csrf' header in the request.
The app should response with  above error for GET req directly, not incoming from inside app.
May be possible with adding _csrf in GET URL or with filters WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: GET requests aren't covered by the default CSRF protection because GET requests are presumed to be read only and thus not harmful. You can likely add it with custom configuration as you suggested.