# Spring security giving 401 on all api end points

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have seen a lot of posts on the same problem, but no solution worked for me.

I have an API secured with spring security as below.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Component
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired private UserService userService;

    public SecurityConfiguration() {
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/shutdown", "/api/register");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I need endpoints `/api/register` and `/actuator/shutdown` available without authentication. But, as it turned out, all the endpoints are returning the same `401` status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this.

```
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
  httpSecurity
        //no authentication needed for these context paths
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/your Urls that dosen't need security/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, it's still giving 401

Comment: Sorry! I added the `antMatcher` to the existing statement instead of replacing it with yours. It's working now. But, as `csrf` is not disabled now, it's giving `403` instead of `401` for access without authentication

Answer (score 1):

We implemented a similar approach as mentioned by Supun Above,

```
http
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and().httpBasic()
```

You can keep 'AUTH_WHITELIST' as below to keep adding multiple Endpoints

```
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        // -- swagger ui
        "/api/register",
        "/actuator/shutdown"
};
```

Comment: It's working, but as `csrf` is not disabled, it's giving `403` instead of `401` for access without authentication

Comment: yea you'll need to handle csrf, check this link if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929943/spring-boot-csrf